# MTD2955V P-Channel positive voltages

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, negative

I'm planning to use this MOSFET to switch about 1.5A at 5 Volts. But the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MTD2955V-D.PDF) is a bit confusing. All voltages are positive, even though they should be negative, shouldn't they? This confuses me a bit. I'm thinking of a circuit like this: [image]

So will be there a problem?

Comment: Do you intend for the transistor to shut off fully?

Comment: The only problem is the text on your diagram, it doesn't make sense to say the -5v or the -2v thing. If your positive supply is 5v and you want to control it with 0v or 3v then more components are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to control the P-FET correctly from a 0-3V MCU I/O pin then you will need to add a couple of components to your circuit. Here is one suggestion as to how to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But why do I need these additional components? What is not correct about using it with the voltage difference between Gate and Source? It would be nice to understand the main problem. Furthermore I should mention that I have to build this circuit for 8 channels. So it would be best too use as less components as possible.
On the other hand, the MOSFET doesn't need to shutdown completely, if the voltage drop is just too high, the LED will block itself.
And my topic question is still not solved: Why are all voltages positive? In different ones they are all negative.

Comment: The NPN transistor and the 220 ohm resistor translate the 0-3V signal from the MCU to a level from 5-0V so that the P-FET turns completely on and off. If you keep the P-FET partially on power will be dissipated in it and it could get rather hot. If you have a heartache with adding the transistors as individual components look at using an IC called a ULN2003A that can support buffering up to 7 channels in one IC. You would still need to add the separate 200 ohm resistors using this IC.

Comment: So if I can interpret your commits correctly, at least I don't have to worry about the positive voltage. I'll see how to build the 3V-to-5V translator

Comment: @GenesisRock - The necessary level translator is drawn right in my answer.

Comment: I know, it's more about building this 8 times as simple as possible :D